# vim + jq :: how to format possibly incorrect text in unsaved file

Tags: buffers, formatting

This is very similar to [how-to-run-bash-command-over-current-file-and-replace-buffer-with-result](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5835/how-to-run-bash-command-over-current-file-and-replace-buffer-with-result)

But I need to know how I can access current buffer when the file does not exist?
i.e.

1. I open vim
2. goto insert mode e,g, press : `i`
3. paste a json, possibly incomplete
4. Run the command `!% jq`

For now I get output as error from jq.

Comment: forgot to add link https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: How is this question different from post you [linked](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5835/778)? The answer seems to be the same, use the filter command with a range. i.e. `:%! jq`

Comment: @PeterRincker The range operator doesn't work with an unnamed or unsaved buffer.

Comment: You can filter a whole buffer with `%!`. Even an unnamed, unsaved buffer. I have tested and verified that `:%!jq '.'` works to prettify JSON.

Comment: correct. filtering works even for unnamed buffers. Please include more information why it wouldn't work for you (e.g. error message).

Comment: I get `E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"` when I try this   oh! just figured out! @PeterRincker is correct i was using `!%` when it should be `%!`